# (g++ 4.8.2) Why do I need to specify -pthread to link sem_post?

Tags: linux, g++, semaphore

In g++ 4.8.2 apparently one has to specify *-pthread* flag to include the reference to *sem_post*.

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/loader.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Why is that? What if one wants to explicitly not have to link that library to ensure no threads are ever run?

Has anything changed?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably it makes sense that synchronization routines would go in the threading library, right?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Not really, semaphores and mutexes can be forms of IPC not _just_ for threads (in fact semaphores were there probably before threads were supported)...why would I need to link "threads" if I don't use them?